# Can an adjective phrase include conjunction?

Tags: adjectives

> Probably, if I had lately left a good home and kind parents, this would have been the hour when I should most keenly have regretted the separation; that wind would then have saddened my heart; this obscure chaos would have disturbed my peace: as it was, I derived from both a strange excitement, **and** reckless and feverish, I wished the wind to howl more wildly, the gloom to deepen to darkness, and the confusion to rise to clamour. (Jane Eyre)

I guess ‘and’ is not necessary or an awkward word, for ‘reckless and feverish’ makes an adjective phrase itself. If this is right, is ‘and’ used just for a literary rhythm, or can an adjective phrase include conjunction?

Comment: I think the question left by @KenB on [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/what-does-onding-on-snaw-mean) would apply here as well: in a book like _Jane Eyre_, it's not reasonable to expect the author would follow all of today's or structural and grammatical practices or vocabulary.

Comment: @J.R. What I want to know is whether ‘and’ used just for a literary rhythm, or can an adjective phrase include conjunction.’ through the example. I do not want to know if she’s written properly to modern criteria. That’s what many commenters make mistakes.

Comment: I'm merely pointing out that it's hard to answer your question in a case like this, because it's quite possible that including conjunctives in an adjective phrase was more commonplace at the time, even if it might be more unusual today. I'm not saying the question is unanswerable, but a new visitor here deserves to know that this work was written over 150 years ago in a style not often mimicked today.

Comment: @J.R. As an English language learner, I want to know the common and basis language structure and its meaning that Chomsky assumed in all languages. What’s the matter in learning a language, if it is old or new, if the learner want to know the language not the style? Why some of you are so sensitive, even a total alien is not sensitive at all?

Comment: Let me try this one more time: Nothing is the matter with wanting to learn the language. There is nothing wrong with this question. I have not downvoted it, I have not voted to close. I have not left a negative comment. I think it's worth pointing out that you are asking about the structure of language that happens to be over 150 years old; however, that doesn't make the question any less valid. Not all comments are meant to criticize; some merely provide additional information for others who visit the site. I assure you, I wasn't being critical, and I was not being "sensitive" about anything.

Comment: Also: when I referred to KenB's comment, I was referring the first part of his comment, not his last sentence. I am not saying, "Don't read _Jane Eyre_" (neither was he). We are merely pointing out that books written in that style are bound to contain confusing phrases and structures, even for native speakers. So, if you ask a question about such matters, many will read the question, and their first reaction will be, "Yup, that's _Jane Eyre_ for ya!" Some of your _Jane Eyre_ questions might be a better fit on ELU, if they stem from more archaic language – but please don't misinterpret that.

Comment: @J.R. I’m tired about the ELU, ELL separation. Probably as you know, I’ve been tossed, go there, and vice versa. Sorry, I do not want to ignore your kind recommendation. But I’ve jolly felt that some are not customers-oriented but deeply-repliers-oriented. And I’m worrying if they’re thinking for what ELU, ELL exist?

Comment: If I found the word "puree" in a recipe, and I was confused, it might be better to ask at Cooking.SE than at English.SE. Each exchange has its own audience. Asking about how to pronounce "Charles I" is ideal for here; we encourage English learners to ask questions like that. Asking about conjunctions in an adjective phrase (using a sentence from _Jane Eyre_ as an example) sounds like a better fit for ELU, as that sounds more like a job for a serious linguist. But the choice is yours; I was only trying to give you – and others who might ask similar questions – some (hopefully) helpful thoughts.

Comment: As for being "tossed" about, it might be worth noting that you asked five questions in the past 8 hours. I answered one, edited two, left a comment on another, and added my comment about "Jane Eyre" to this one. In that time, you've gotten helpful, accurate answers from Barrie, Bill, Jim, Shawn, and Stoney. As of right now, I see 4 upvotes and 0 downvotes. I didn't even mention ELU until this dialogue had gone back-and-forth a couple times, after I was told "commenters make mistakes" and asked, "why are some of you so sensitive?" All told, I don't think this community is being unsupportive.

Comment: @J.R. My 2¢: The error this community falls into is the casual assumption that any difficulty with JE is probably attributable to its age. In fact, exactly **one** of Listenever's 23 questions about JE has involved an 'obsolete' usage (and that one was *not* the question to which your first comment links, which concerns a still-living dialect form). **99% of the language in JE is current Standard English and in no way exceptional**. The community is too quick to dismiss these questions, which are the same questions Listenever asks about *Harry Potter*.

Comment: @StoneyB: I agree with all that you say, except for maybe the part about the community being "too quick to dismiss the questions." Mentioning that certain language has an out-of-date ring is not quite the same as treating as [unworthy of serious consideration](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dismiss). That said, your comment prompted me to look back at the history of the Jane Eyre questions, and I noticed that comments hinting that "this is an olde book" go back further than I realized. I'll try not to beat that dead horse (or utter execrations about this matter) anymore. :^)

Comment: @J.R. A very gracious response. The only real difference between Brontë and, say, Ann Rice is punctuation: Brontë uses long periods (though not as long as Faulkner); so Listenever probably reads JE more easily than many native speakers, precisely because it's no more foreign to her than is Harry Potter, while native speakers see an 80-word sentence and their eyes glaze over!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Reckless and feverish* pre-modifies modifies *I*. If you imagine a comma after *and*, the meaning should become clear.